# Discriminant of product of fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a field with two galois extensions $L$ and $L'$ with degree $n$ and $n'$ such that $L \cap L'=K $. Let $\omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_n$, respectively $\omega'_1,\omega'_2,...,\omega'_{n'}$,integral basis of $L/K$, respectively $L'/K$, with discriminant $d$, respectively $d'$.
We know that if $d$ and $d'$ are relatively prime then $\{ \omega_i\omega'_j\}_{i,j}$ is an integral basis of $LL'$ with discriminant $d^{n'}d'ⁿ$. (Neukirch pag 13,14)
But what happens if $d$ and $d'$ aren't relatively prime? In particular, if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ then discriminant is independent of the choice of a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis and I think that
$$d_{\mathbb{Q}}(LL')=(d,d')^2d^{n'}d'ⁿ$$
where $(d,d')$ are the greatest common divisor between $d$ and $d'$. But I don't know how to prove it. Is it true?